# looking for the location of next_posts_link() in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am not able to find the location of function next_posts_link(). I am looking for its implementation. Can you please tell in which folder should I look for inorder to be able to see the implementation of this function(). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp-includes/link-template.php. ~Line 1509

References the function above it, get_next_posts_link().